# Is there any way in Unity to make something like decal projector from HDRP in build-in pipeline?

Tags: unity-game-engine, decal

Is there any way in Unity to make something like decal projector from HDRP in build-in pipeline? Tried Easy Decals but they doesn't work, at least 2019 version.

Comment: Check out [Rendering Command Buffers](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/02/06/extending-unity-5-rendering-pipeline-command-buffers/) . There is a decal example there.

Comment: @Pluto Yes, I saw this, but it's a little bit old, does it work with 2019.3?

Comment: The project is also in [Unity 2019.3 Manual: Graphics Command Buffers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GraphicsCommandBuffers.html) so it should work just fine.

Comment: @Pluto Unfortunately it's kinda proof of concept: in my scene decals even sometimes disappear when I move or rotate camera :( In demmo scene they work ok though.

Comment: I just had a quick look at the project and I think the reason your decals disappear is because the command buffer gets added to the camera only if the object that has the script `DeferredDecalRenderer` attached is in camera view (CB is added in `OnWillRenderObject`, i think this is done to capture the editor cameras not juts the game camera). In the demo project the script is attached to that big plane. Just as a test to see if this is the problem put a cube in front of the camera (as a child so it is always in view) and attach the script to it.

Comment: Just have added it in a new project and it doesn't work at all. And when I add steamvr player in example project it locked player camera, so it became always rotated by some angle.

Comment: I read all its source and done everything the same way, no luck

Comment: Try changing `OnWillRenderObject` to `OnPreRender` and attach `DeferredDecalRenderer` to the camera instead. (this will mean that decals will not show in the editor but hopefully will work in game). And make sure that the camera render path is deferred.

Comment: Strangely, it worked. It still looks like a proof of concept (no culling, inconvenience with renderer script) but it works in VR! Never know where are headset glitches or my fails :)